# Tried to tighten the brakes, won't grip at all

Tags: repair, cable, drum-brakes, roller-brake

I have a big problem. I know I could get this fixed with a mechanic, but really want to learn how to do it myself. I tried to fix (fool around) with my brakes a little the other day. The brakes are Shimano Nexave BR-IM70-R [rollerbrakes](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rollerbrakes.html).

I loosened the "thing" that connects the cable to the actual brake pads, but when I tried to fasten it again the brakes don't grip at all. That is to say, when I pull the lever at the handle, the cable is pulled, but doesn't grip the brake at all.

I have tried watching videos online, but none of them seems to deal with this problem. Also, I have tried to find the name of the brakes, but I am unsure where to look at the bicycle. Hope that someone would be able to guide me on the right path

Here are some pictures:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the cable slipping / not under tension?

Comment: Yeah, it slips right through. I am thinking it might be because it doesn't grip where it should!

Comment: You probably should post some pictures of what brakes you have and stuff. But it sounds like you just loosened the cable, and didn't cinch it up enough.

Comment: Good idea. I have found the name of the brakes and added some pictures

Comment: I've edited your question a bit, cause they aren't mechanical disc brakes but roller brakes (a type of drum brake). Its not a piece of hardware I'm familiar with, but maybe someone else is.

Comment: I actually found the solution. The inner cable (wire) goes through a small screw which simply needed to be tightened many times harder than I had thought. So should be good to go. Now I only need to figure out how to tighten the actual brakes, which were my initial problems.

Comment: Good old Sheldon Brown's site has the full monty: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rollerbrakes.html

Comment: To adjust the brake you use the *barrel adjuster* on the brake lever. If you google for a guide on adjusting 'V-brakes' or 'linear pull' brakes you should find something applicable as the cable attaches to the brake in a similar fashion and the adjuster is at the lever in those systems.

Comment: @pkpkPPkafa - have you been doing regular maintenance on it? like the lubrication and stuff?

Comment: Looking at this page I see there is also a barrel adjuster on the brake unit itself https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rollerbrakes.html

Comment: @Batman, no unfortunately not. Have been living away from where the bike was for years, and since it has been used by other people, it is not in a good state. Unfortunately ....

Comment: @pkpkPPkafa - the unfortunate thing with roller brakes is that if anything has gone wrong inside the brake (e.g. its been run without grease), you'll have to get a new brake. Shimano doesn't make parts to service them. But, I'm just hoping you need to increase the cable tension (and maybe put in some grease).

Comment: That really doesn't sound good. Are they expensive to buy?

Answer (score 4):

On the first picture, if you look closely at the cable right to the bolt at the center, you will see deformation marks from the previous clamping. The position where you have clamped the cable seems to be too slack. That is, too much cable is left between the lever and the pinch bolt.

To fix it, loose the cable, press the "thing" that rotates when you press the brake lever clockwise, and clamp the cable again at the new place.

You may end up taking up too much slack, permanently pressing the brake pads against the rotor or drum; in this case, find a compromise position between too slack and too tight. It can be done by using the adjustment barrel at the lever, if you have one there.